# Setting a date and revision number as variables in tfs 2017

Tags: .net, .net-core, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create a variable named NugetVersionNumber with the value a date format of $(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr) with the revision at the end.

e.g.

2018.8.23.1

How do I set a process variable to construct this format without changing the build.buildnumber variable?

Answer (score 1):

It's not able to directly use  `$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` as a [**user-defined variables**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#user-defined-variables). `(Date:yyyyMMdd)` is a [token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/options#tokens) of build number format not a general variable.

The only way to do this is setting your build number with `(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` format. And then directly use the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` variable .

Since you are going to use this as a Nuget Package Version. You could directly check the *Use the build number to version package* in [Nuget Package task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-nuget#use-the-build-number-to-version-package).

> To use the build number, check the Use build number to version package
>   box and follow the line's instructions (hover over the blue *i* icon)
>   to set the build version format string. You must set the build version
>   format string to have at least three parts separated by periods to
>   avoid an error in NuGet packaging. The default build version format
>   string is `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)`, so a simple change is to add a
>   zero at the end and a period between the date and build counter:
>   `$(date:yyyyMMdd).$(rev:.r).0`.

Comment: I believe the period between date and build counter already was handled by `$(rev:.r)`, as this means period and then release number. The correct for NuGet packaging should be `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r).0`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work. I realized that tfs 2017 produces a build variable called 'OutputedVersion' when using the task 'version .NET Core assemblies' and with the regex filter extract the date from the build.buildnumber variable.