# Date and Rev variables do not get expanded

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have the following pipeline. As you can see i set the Informational version to a string. This gets used in a template and is injected into my output dlls.

```yaml
- name: fileVersion
  value: '1.0.0.$(Build.BuildId)'
- name: informationalVersion
  value: '1.0.0.$(Build.BuildId)-Alpha+$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: BuildTemplates
      type: git
      name: HMI/BuildTemplates

extends:
  template: netFx/Jobs/netFx.Build.yml@BuildTemplates
```

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  steps:
  - template: ../../NuGet/Steps/NuGet.Restore.yml
  - template: ../Steps/netFx.Build.Version.yml
  - template: ../Steps/netFx.Build.yml
```

```yaml
steps:
- task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@2
  inputs:
    Path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    FileNames: |
      **\AssemblyInfo.cs
      **\AssemblyInfo.vb
    InsertAttributes: true
    FileEncoding: 'auto'
    WriteBOM: true
    VersionNumber: '$(assemblyVersion)'
    # File version in windows explorer
    FileVersionNumber: '$(fileVersion)'
    # Product version in windows explorer
    InformationalVersion: '$(informationalVersion)'
    LogLevel: 'verbose'
    FailOnWarning: false
    DisableTelemetry: true
```

The issue is that these variables dont get expanded: `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` which i can see when i inspect the dll:

[image]

`$(Build.BuildId)` seems to work like it should. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly use `$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` as variables in yaml pipeline. You have to use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` to get its value.

So you can configure the build number to be `$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` by defining the `name` attribute for the yaml pipeline. And then refer to variable `$(Build.BuildNumber)` directly. See below example:

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

variables:
- name: fileVersion
  value: '1.0.0.$(Build.BuildId)'
- name: informationalVersion
  value: '1.0.0.$(Build.BuildId)-Alpha+$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

See [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) here. Or check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842392/setting-a-date-and-revision-number-as-variables-in-tfs-2017) thread.